# By iterating, dynamically set variables using strings from array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I got stuck. I need to create 4 new elements which will have the same class and different ID. The point is that I do not want to repeat a code... but my loop does not work.

I was trying to overcome this challenge for like 2 hours already (doing also a lot of research in Google), trying to find out what is going on using console.log and printing elements inside the iteration. Then, I needed to print console.dir to see attributes of created [object HTMLDivElement].

The code looks like this:

```
columnsArray = ["first", "second", "third", "fourth"]
for (var i = 0; i < columnsArray.length; i++ ) {
    let name = columnsArray[i]
    name = document.createElement("div");
    name.className = "container"
    name.setAttribute("id", name.name)
    document.querySelector("#board" + boardId).appendChild(name);
}
```

I wonder if there is any relatively simple way (worth of trying) to achieve my aim? Except for this:

```
let first = document.createElement("div");
let second = document.createElement("div");
let third = document.createElement("div");
let fourth = document.createElement("div");

first.className = "container"
second.className = "container"
third.className = "container"
fourth.className = "container"

first.setAttribute = "first"
second.setAttribute = "second"
third.setAttribute = "third"
fourth.setAttribute = "fourth"


document.querySelector("#board" + boardId).appendChild(first);
document.querySelector("#board" + boardId).appendChild(second);
document.querySelector("#board" + boardId).appendChild(third);
document.querySelector("#board" + boardId).appendChild(fourth);
```

Thanks in advance for help;)

Comment: Why are you setting the `.setAttribute` method to a String?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're overriding the ID value from `columnsArray` in your loop by creating it as an element.

Create your element within a new variable:

```
columnsArray = ["first", "second", "third", "fourth"]

for (var i = 0; i < columnsArray.length; i++ ) {
    // get the ID value from the array
    let name = columnsArray[i];
    // create a new element
    let element = document.createElement("div");
    // set its name
    element.className = "container"
    // set the ID value to columnsArray[i] (name)
    element.setAttribute("id", name)
    // append to board
    document.querySelector("#board" + boardId).appendChild(element);
}
```

Comment: I was so close, yet so far... I do not know why I was trying so hard to have the same name of variable everywhere. Thanks, shame on me:p

Answer (score 0):

Your loop works fine, you just can't access the name in the way you think.

You have to set the id like this:

```
name.setAttribute("id", columnsArray[i])
```

`name.name` doesn't exist.

```js
columnsArray = ["first", "second", "third", "fourth"];
boardId = 1;
for (var i = 0; i < columnsArray.length; i++ ) {
    let name = document.createElement("div");
    name.className = "container"
    
    name.setAttribute("id", columnsArray[i]) // set name.id to columnsArray[i]
    
    name.innerHTML = "DIV id="+columnsArray[i]
    document.querySelector("#board" + boardId).appendChild(name);
    console.log(name, name.id)
}
```

```html
<div id="board1"></div>
```

Comment: I copied the code after my desperate attempts of getting something more out of "name", that's why there was name.name, which of course didn't make a sense at all ;) thanks for your efforts

Answer (score 0):

Use `name.setAttribute("id", columnsArray[i])` instead of `name.setAttribute("id", name.name)`

After that use

```
name.innerHTML = columnsArray[i]; //Replace it for some info or element
document.querySelector("#board" + boardId).appendChild(name);
```

Answer (score 0):

use this:

```
columnsArray = ["first", "second", "third", "fourth"]

for (i in columnsArray) {
  let name = columnsArray[i]
  name = document.createElement("div");
  name.className = "container"
  name.setAttribute("id",columnsArray[i])
  document.getElementById('boardId').appendChild(name);
}
```